# Syncronization issue in Verifix while validating received FIX messages

Tags: automation, fix-protocol

I'm using this FIX automation tool called VeriFIX to validate FIX messages. The problem I'm facing is, in my script I'm expecting an acknowledgement message from server in different session but there's a synchronization issue here.

The comes before my script arrives in that session and hence my scripts then keeps on waiting indefinitely for the message which has already being sent by the server.
Can anyone help me out on how to overcome this synchronization issue of VeriFIX, there are very limited options available with the tool and I couldn't find any thing useful.

Comment: Please elaborate a little more. In its current format, it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: The question is not worded well, and thus difficult to understand, but in VeriFIX you can introduce a pause in a script if you need to delay further processing. You may consider contacting [Greenline support](http://www.greenlinetech.com/support/) directly for this issue, assuming you have a license.

Answer (score 0):

What Sumbad is saying is the expected message has been received before the script has moved onto the step that expects the message.
To overcome this with veriFix Sumbad you should de-select the box that clears the queue after the last sucessfully received message.